# Javascript Multi Array not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi I am trying to print out the first element and the element attached to that element in an array.  I am getting 'helloh' in firefox and 'helloundefined' in IE.  Does anyone know why this isn't working.

Here is a jsfiddle..    http://jsfiddle.net/ZtuAu/

```
<script language=javascript> 
var test = new Array();
test[0] = new Array();

test[0] = "hello";
test[0][0] = "world";
document.write(test[0] + test[0][0]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array

```
var test = new Array();
```

If you want to insert an item into it, use `push`

```
test[0] = new Array(); // not this way
test.push(new Array()); // this way
```

Because you want the array to update its length property etc.

So, you do this:

```
test[0] = new Array();
test[0] = "hello";
```

You're assigning the same thing twice, so naturally, only the second assignment holds. So we have

```
test[0] == "hello"
```

Then, in FireFox, you can use `[]` to access any character of the string

```
test[0][0] == "hello"[0] == "h"
```

Apparently, in IE you cannot do that, so you get `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

`test[0]` can only have one value.  You're trying to give it two values.  And, you're also finding out that only some browsers allow using array syntax to retrieve particular characters in a string.

First, you do this:

```
test[0] = new Array();
```

Then, you do this:

```
test[0] = "hello";
```

The second one replaces your first one so that `test[0]` does not contain an array, it contains a single string `"hello"` so when do do this:

```
test[0][0] = "world"
```

you are trying to assign `[0]` on a the `"hello"` string in `test[0]` which is not allowed by the string object (so it does nothing).

Then, when you try to read `test[0][0]` in your `document.write()` statement, you are trying to do `[0]` on the `"hello"` string that's in `test[0]`.  Indexing a string with array syntax is not technically allowed by the string object, but some browsers permit it anyway as a shortcut means of retrieving individual characters from a string.  That's why you get a different result in different browsers (it returns the 0th character of the `"hello"` string which is `"h"`).

Note: if you actually want to retrieve a particular character of a string, use `charAt(n)`.  See [MDN for doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Perhaps what you want do do is this:

```
<script language=javascript> 
var test = new Array();
test[0] = "hello";
test[1] = "world";
document.write(test[0] + test[1]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the third line (`test[0] = new Array();`), you set `test[0]` to a new array.

On the next line (`test[0] = "hello";`), you set it to a string.

Then with `test[0][0] = "world";` you try to set that string's first index to "world".

That's like trying to do `"hello"[0] = "world";`. You can't do that. The String object in JavaScript is immutable.

---

`var test = Array();` makes a 1 dimensional structure... like this:

```
0 - [_]
1 - [_]
2 - [_]
3 - [_]
4 - [_]
```

Then, setting the first spot to a new array gives it a second dimension (but only in the first spot).

```
0 - [_][_][_][_][_]
1 - [_]
2 - [_]
3 - [_]
4 - [_]
```

Then, setting the first spot to `"Hello"` gets rid of the array you put there.

```
0 - ["Hello"]
1 - [_]
2 - [_]
3 - [_]
4 - [_]
```

At this point, `test[0]` is `"Hello"`. Not the standard `Array` that you want it to be. You can't set `[0]` of a string.

---

When you ask try to set `[0]` of a String like `"Hello"`, nothing actually happens, so the line `test[0][0] = "world";` isn't really doing anything at all!.

Deep down, Strings are the same as Arrays. Array operations can even be applied to a String. The extent to which browsers expose the underlying similarities isn't really consistent. In FF, Chrome, and Safari, you'll `test[0][0]` is getting `[0]` of `"Hello"`. In those browsers, Hello is kinda the same as `["H","e","l","l","o"]`. So, `test[0][0]` = `"Hello"[0]` = `"H"`. IE doesn't treat strings that way. That's why you're seeing inconsistent behavior.

Hope this helped!

EDIT: As someone else has already suggested, using `charAt(x)` is the function you should use when trying to pull a character at a specific position from a string.

Answer (score 0):

You first make test[0][0] an array, and then just put a string into it. So `test[0]` is `hello`, and `test[0][0]` is `h` as it is the 0th element of the `hello` string. So you get `hello` + `h`